# Strapi: When uploading image it converts thumbnail to black & white

Tags: strapi

I have my strapi project connected with Cloudflare R2 using `strapi-provider-cloudflare-r2` plugin.
When I upload image locally thumbnail is generated correctly but when uploaded from deployed environment thumbnails look like this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI4WY.png)

And same in Cloudflare. Image thumbnail is black & white. Maybe it's something to do when uploading an image but have not had any luck figuring this out.

My middlewares.ts file:

```
    name: "strapi::security",
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          "connect-src": ["'self'", "https:"],
          "img-src": [
            "'self'",
            "data:",
            "blob:",
            "market-assets.strapi.io",
            env("CF_PUBLIC_ACCESS_URL")
              ? env("CF_PUBLIC_ACCESS_URL").replace(/^https?:\/\//, "")
              : "",
          ],
          "media-src": [
            "'self'",
            "data:",
            "blob:",
            "market-assets.strapi.io",
            env("CF_PUBLIC_ACCESS_URL")
              ? env("CF_PUBLIC_ACCESS_URL").replace(/^https?:\/\//, "")
              : "",
          ],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },`
```

When uploading in deployed Strapi state it should display correct thumbnail images.

Comment: Still can't figure out the problem..